# converting factor data frame to date data frame

Tags: r, dataframe

I have such a data frame(df) which is just a sample:

```
df<- as.data.frame(as.factor(
c("16.04.2015", "04.08.2014", "11.09.2013",  "20.11.2015", "04.04.2014")))
```

How can I change this data frame into date formatted data frame. I will be very glad for nay help. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @RStudent. That works very well. Thanks  a lot.

Comment: @RStudent could you give the answer in the box and not in a comment? This will allow oercim to accept your answer and close the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following:

```
df[] <- as.Date(df[,1], format = "%d.%m.%Y")
```